# Find the nth number of fibonacci sequence

Tags: python, fibonacci

I have this code, with `input_number = 10`. I have to make a **fibonacci** sequence with condition: `fibo[-2] < input_number < fibo[-1]`

```
def fibonacci(input_number):
  a = 0
  b = 1
  fibo=[a, b]
  while b < input_number:
    a, b = b, a+b
    fibo.append(b)
    print(fibo)
```

and the output was like this, just as I expected:

```
[0, 1, 1]
[0, 1, 1, 2]
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3]
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5]
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8]
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13]
```

But the problem now is that I want to call the last fibonacci number which is 13 and the output supposed to be `"The last fibonacci number is 13 and it is the 8th fibonacci number"`. But I can't call the number of 13 because it is an integer and not a list.

How can I convert that into a list?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "call the last fibonacci number"? You have `b` and `fibo` which should give you what you need in two different ways.

Comment: Please define *“call the last Fibonacci number”*. You *call* functions, not integers or lists.

Comment: do you want your function to return 13? then add `return fibo[-1]` after the loop

Comment: This is what happen if I printed out 'b'
1
2
3
5
8
13
and I thought I can call the number of 13 if I typed print(b[-1]) but it showed an error : 'int' object is not subscriptable.

Sorry for the lack explanation, I'm new into this

Comment: you need return **fibo[-1]**, not `b[-1]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably just need the syntax to access the fibo array. Hope the below helps:

```
def fibonacci(input_number):
    a = 0
    b = 1
    fibo = [a, b]
    while b < input_number:
        a, b = b, a + b
        fibo.append(b)
        print(fibo)

    print(f'fibonacci number {len(fibo)} is {fibo[len(fibo) - 1]}')
    print('===')
    i = 0
    while i < len(fibo):
       print(f'fibonacci number {i + 1} is {fibo[i]}')
       i += 1

fibonacci(10)
```

Result:

```
[0, 1, 1]
[0, 1, 1, 2]
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3]
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5]
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8]
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13]
fibonacci number 8 is 13
===
fibonacci number 1 is 0
fibonacci number 2 is 1
fibonacci number 3 is 1
fibonacci number 4 is 2
fibonacci number 5 is 3
fibonacci number 6 is 5
fibonacci number 7 is 8
fibonacci number 8 is 13
```

Comment: `fibo[-1]` is a much more concise way of accessing the last index of fibo

Answer (score 0):

`fibo` is the list containing all of your values. To get the last value of the list you can index it by -1, so `fibo[-1]`. We can then determine which Fibonacci number fibo[-1] is by getting the length of the list, `len(fibo)`.

I wont write the full answer for you, but put this

```py
print("fibo[-1]==",fibo[-1], " len(fibo)==", len(fibo))
```

outside the while loop, and I think you'll be able to figure it out from there.

Answer (score 0):

All the previous codes have a greater time complexity.

However, there is a separate way of doing it in constant time, if we consider the pow() or ** and sqrt() function to work in constant time.

Considering the series to be in the following format
=> 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, ...

Where,
0 ----> 0 th fibonacci number 
1 ----> 1 th fibonacci number 
1 ----> 2 th fibonacci number 
2 ----> 3 rd fibonacci number 
3 ----> 4 th fibonacci number 
5 ----> 5 th fibonacci number

The mathematical formula to calculate the nth Fibonacci number in a constant time/O(1) is:

[image]

The python code should be something like this:

```
from math import sqrt

# n defines the nth fibonacci number
n = 5

def fib(n):
    p = ( 1 + sqrt(5) ) / 2
    q = ( 1 - sqrt(5) ) / 2
    return int((p**n-q**n) / sqrt(5)) 
    # to counter float value from the division operator int is used

print(fib(n))
```

Input:

```
5
```

Output:

```
5
```

Comment: The fifth number in the Fibonacci sequence is 3